# Authentication in pyramid

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid

I am trying to set up a basic navigation in pyramid (1.4a1). According to the tutorial given at [tutorial](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/Akhet/auth.html) *groupfinder* is called once we remember after login is successful. This works on my local but when I try the same on a server it doesn't call groupfinder at all and keeps looping between the two routes. Here's my code snippet:

```
from pyramid.security import remember, forget, authenticated_userid
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound, HTTPForbidden
from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry
from pyramid.url import route_url
from pyramid.view import view_config, forbidden_view_config


@view_config(route_name='index',
    renderer='templates:templates/index.pt',
    permission='Authenticated')
def index_view(request):
    try:
        full_name = (request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name)
    except:
        full_name = "Anonymous"
    return {"label": label, "user_name": full_name}

@forbidden_view_config()
def forbidden(request):

    if authenticated_userid(request):
        return HTTPForbidden()

    loc = request.route_url('login.view', _query=(('next', request.path),))
    return HTTPFound(location=loc)

@view_config(route_name='login.view')
def login_view(request):

    came_from =  request.route_url('index')

    #perform some authentication
    username = 'xyz'
    if authenticate(username):
        headers = remember(request, username)
        #user was authenticated. Must call groupfinder internally and set principal as authenticated.
        return HTTPFound(location=came_from, headers=headers)
    else:
        return HTTPForbidden('Could not authenticate.')

    return HTTPForbidden('Could not authenticate.')
```

Also, my ACL looks like:
`__acl__ = [(Allow, Authenticated, 'Authenticated'), DENY_ALL]`.

Can someone tell my why groupfinder is not being called? Is the request routing happening properly? Also, the same code works on my local setup fine. So there is no problem in groupfinder or ACL authorization settings.

Thanks much!

Comment: Is there any difference in the configuration ini between your local setup and what's running on the server?

Comment: No. Its exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of debugging and digging up I found out that the issue was very simple. Don't know the reason for the behavior but I had added `secure = True` attribute when calling `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy()`. When I removed this attribute, it started working.